# How to create a swipe effect in Qt 4.8?

Tags: qt, qml, swipe, gesture

I need to create a screen where the user will swipe right or left and top or down and on each of these I will present another screen. It would be like a cross where the center and each end is another screen of the system.

I tried using GestureArea, but its only event that worked was onTapAndHold, other events like onSwipe don't run. I later found out that Qt 4.8 has a bug in GestureArea and other events don't work. The problem is that the onTapAndHold event runs on click as well and I just want it to run with the swipe event.

[image: Cross]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!

How I did it:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import Qt.labs.gestures 1.0

import "module"

Rectangle {
    id: recMainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 480
    color: "#00000000"

    property string strActualScreen: "screenCenter"

    function funSwipeScreens(swipeArea)
    {
        if ((!panBottomCenter.running) && (!panCenterBottom.running) &&
            (!panCenterLeft.running) &&  (!panCenterRight.running) &&
            (!panCenterTop.running) &&  (!panLeftCenter.running) &&
            (!panRightCenter.running) &&  (!panTopCenter.running))
        {
            if (swipeArea == "top")
            {
                if (strActualScreen == "screenBottom")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenCenter";

                    marLeft.enabled = true;
                    marRight.enabled = true;
                    marBottom.enabled = true;

                    panBottomCenter.start();
                }
                else if (strActualScreen == "screenCenter")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenTop";

                    marTop.enabled = false;
                    marLeft.enabled = false;
                    marRight.enabled = false;

                    panCenterTop.start();
                }
            }
            else if (swipeArea == "bottom")
            {
                if (strActualScreen == "screenTop")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenCenter";

                    marTop.enabled = true;
                    marLeft.enabled = true;
                    marRight.enabled = true;

                    panTopCenter.start();
                }
                else if (strActualScreen == "screenCenter")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenBottom";

                    marLeft.enabled = false;
                    marRight.enabled = false;
                    marBottom.enabled = false;

                    panCenterBottom.start();
                }
            }
            else if (swipeArea == "left")
            {
                if (strActualScreen == "screenRight")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenCenter";

                    marBottom.enabled = true;
                    marRight.enabled = true;
                    marTop.enabled = true;

                    panRightCenter.start();
                }
                else if (strActualScreen == "screenCenter")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenLeft";

                    marLeft.enabled = false;
                    marBottom.enabled = false;
                    marTop.enabled = false;

                    panCenterLeft.start();
                }
            }
            else if (swipeArea == "right")
            {
                if (strActualScreen == "screenLeft")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenCenter";

                    marLeft.enabled = true;
                    marBottom.enabled = true;
                    marTop.enabled = true;

                    panLeftCenter.start();
                }
                else if (strActualScreen == "screenCenter")
                {
                    strActualScreen = "screenRight";

                    marBottom.enabled = false;
                    marRight.enabled = false;
                    marTop.enabled = false;

                    panCenterRight.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaCenter
        x: 0
        y: 0
        source: "qrc:/qml/centerScreen"
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaTop
        x: 0
        y: -480
        source: "qrc:/qml/topScreen"
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaBottom
        x: 0
        y: 480
        source: "qrc:/qml/bottomScreen"
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaLeft
        x: -800
        y: 0
        source: "qrc:/qml/leftScreen"
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaRight
        x: 800
        y: 0
        source: "qrc:/qml/rightScreen"
    }

    GestureArea {
        id: marLeft
        x: 0
        y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 280
        focus: true
        onTapAndHold: {
            funSwipeScreens("left");
        }
    }

    GestureArea {
        id: marRight
        x: 700
        y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 280
        focus: true
        onTapAndHold: {
            funSwipeScreens("right");
        }
    }

    GestureArea {
        id: marTop
        x: 100
        y: 0
        width: 600
        height: 100
        focus: true
        onTapAndHold: {
            funSwipeScreens("top");
        }
    }

    GestureArea {
        id: marBottom
        x: 100
        y: 380
        width: 600
        height: 100
        focus: true
        onTapAndHold: {
            funSwipeScreens("bottom");
        }
    }

    // TOP ANIMATIONS
    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panCenterTop

        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "y"; from: 0; to: 480; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaTop; property: "y"; from: -480; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panTopCenter

        NumberAnimation { target: loaTop; property: "y"; from: 0; to: -480; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "y"; from: 480; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    // BOTTOM ANIMATIONS
    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panCenterBottom

        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "y"; from: 0; to: -480; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaBottom; property: "y"; from: 480; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panBottomCenter

        NumberAnimation { target: loaBottom; property: "y"; from: 0; to: 480; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "y"; from: -480; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    // LEFT ANIMATIONS
    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panCenterLeft

        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "x"; from: 0; to: 800; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaLeft; property: "x"; from: -800; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panLeftCenter

        NumberAnimation { target: loaLeft; property: "x"; from: 0; to: -800; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "x"; from: 800; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    // RIGHT ANIMATIONS
    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panCenterRight

        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "x"; from: 0; to: -800; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaRight; property: "x"; from: 800; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    ParallelAnimation {
        id: panRightCenter

        NumberAnimation { target: loaRight; property: "x"; from: 0; to: 800; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        NumberAnimation { target: loaCenter; property: "x"; from: -800; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Well ... after checking the wrong behaviors that the GestureArea I used above caused, because they respond to the click on the onTapAndHold event and I just wanted the answer to the swipe event, I decided to remove them and make a swipe simulation using MouseArea. .

The swipe action has greatly improved and the click event issue presented by GestureArea has been resolved but has caused the MouseAreas overlay issue.

This did not exist when using GestureArea as it did not prevent a click on a MouseArea positioned below it and MouseAreas overlap prevents it.

Anyway, the solution for the GestureArea swipe event I describe below:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    preventStealing: true

    property real reaSpeed: 0.0 // calculates drag speed for swipe to run
    property int intStartY: 0 // starting point pressed by the user's finger

    property bool booTracing: false //controls the analyzed drag length

    onPressed: {
        intStartY = mouse.y;

        reaSpeed = 0;

        booTracing = true;
    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        if (!booTracing)
        {
            return;
        }

        reaSpeed = (intStartY - mouse.y) / 2.0;

        if ((reaSpeed > 50) && (mouse.y < (parent.height * 0.2)))
        {
            booTracing = false;

            if (booIsShowMenu)
            {
                sigStartHideMenu();
            }

            funSwipeScreens("bottom");
        }
    }
}
```

I am checking a way to handle MouseAreas overlay.

Comment: for me it's giving this error: module "Qt.labs.gestures" is not installed.@msribeir for QT 5.8

Comment: @JimitRupani my solution is for Qt 4.8. I know GestureArea has been discontinued in Qt 5 (which is why this error message occurs) and has been replaced by PinchArea, but I have never used it, so I don't know if it works the same way.